# Upsert only if incoming entry's date is newer than current date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database table with columns `name`, `date` and `color`. The name is the primary key.

I want to run an upsert command:

- If it's a first-time entry for that `name`, then it should just insert it
- If the `name` already exists, I want to update the entry for that `name` only if the date of the incoming entry is newer than the date of the entry currently in there for that name

Using a Python SQL query that looks like

```
f"INSERT INTO test (name, date, color) 
VALUES ({variable_name}, {variable_date}, {variable_color})
ON CONFLICT (name) WHERE name = '{variable_name}' and '{variable_date}' > date
DO UPDATE SET (name, date, color) = (EXCLUDED.name, EXCLUDED.date, EXCLUDED.color)"
```

What is unexpectedly happening is that it is updating the row regardless of whether the `variable_date` is newer than what's currently in there or not.

I recreated it in SQLFiddle below. The second entry with 2014-01-01 is replacing the 2015-01-01 entry despite the date not being newer as indicated by the `WHERE` clause.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6a594/8

Why is this not working and what is a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is affecting the conflict test, not the update. Your query string should look like:

```
"
INSERT INTO test (name, date, color) 
VALUES ({variable_name}, {variable_date}, {variable_color})
  ON CONFLICT (name) DO
    UPDATE
      SET date = EXCLUDED.date,
          color = EXCLUDED.color
      WHERE date < EXCLUDED.date
"
```

Consider renaming the columns `date` and `name`. `DATE` is a reserved keyword and `NAME` is a non-reserved keyword. Neither should be used as column names.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. On a side note, I also would be able to remove the name = EXCLUDED.name in the WHERE clause right? Since it is implied by the conflict itself? Tried it and it worked without it, but not sure if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @Pensw, you are correct, `name = EXCLUDED.name` is redundant in the `WHERE` clause because the `UPDATE` action is always for the conflicting row. I've edited the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.